# как сделать Fragment аналогичный Activity

Tags: android, activity, android-fragment

Задача: есть активити с listView и editText, как из этого активити сделать точно такой же, только фрагмент? Пытаюсь просто копипастом перенести код с активити в фрагмент -  выдает ошибку

```
Error:(65, 9) error: unreachable statement
Error:(68, 5) error: missing return statement
```

ListActivity.java

```
public class ListActivity extends Activity{

private ListView mListView;
private EditText mInputSearch;

private ArrayList<String> mList;
private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    mInputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

    mList = new ArrayList<String>();
    mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mList);

    mInputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
            ListActivity.this.mAdapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
        }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                      int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });

    fillArray();

    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

}

private void fillArray() {

    mList.add("Lorem");
    mList.add("Ipsum");
    mList.add("Dolor");
    mList.add("Sit");
    mList.add("Amet");
    mList.add("Consectetur");
    mList.add("Adipiscing");
    mList.add("Elit");
    mList.add("Fusce");
    mList.add("Pharetra");
    mList.add("Luctus");
    mList.add("Sodales");

    Collections.sort(mList);
}
}
```

ListFragment.java

```
public class ListFragment extends Fragment {

private ListView mListView;
private EditText mInputSearch;

private ArrayList<String> mList;
private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mList = new ArrayList<String>();
    mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getParent(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mList);

    mInputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
            ListFragment.this.mAdapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
        }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                      int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });

    fillArray();

    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_list, container, false);

    mListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(R.id.listView, container);
    mInputSearch = (EditText) inflater.inflate(R.id.inputSearch,container);

}

private void fillArray() {

    mList.add("Lorem");
    mList.add("Ipsum");
    mList.add("Dolor");
    mList.add("Sit");
    mList.add("Amet");
    mList.add("Consectetur");
    mList.add("Adipiscing");
    mList.add("Elit");
    mList.add("Fusce");
    mList.add("Pharetra");
    mList.add("Luctus");
    mList.add("Sodales");

    Collections.sort(mList);
}
}
```

приложения падает в этом методе, на двух последних строках

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_list, container, false);

    mListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(R.id.listView, container);
    mInputSearch = (EditText) inflater.inflate(R.id.inputSearch,container);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Судя по вашему вопросу и комментариям вы плохо понимаете жизненный цикл активити и фрагментов, а именно то, в каком порядке вызываются их методы, и какую роль они играют.

Перенесите код из метода `onCreate` фрагмента в метод `onCreateView`. Он должен быть примерно таким(предполагается что в `activity_list` есть нужные `View` с указанными id):

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_list, container, false);

    mList = new ArrayList<String>();
    fillArray();

    mListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    mInputSearch = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

    mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getParent(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mList);
    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mInputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
            ListFragment.this.mAdapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
        }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                      int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

И еще я бы посоветовал произвести рефакторинг:

- убрать из переменных класса `mList`, пусть это будет локальная
  переменная метода `onCreateView`, в дальнейшем если понадобиться
  получить элемент списка, то его можно будет получить из адаптера;
- метод `fillArray` изменить таким образом, чтобы он сам создавал
  список, заполнял и возвращал его, т.к. в вашем случае если вызвать
  этот метод не в свое время, то приложение упадет с `NPE`, т.е.
  ваш код зависит от того выполнится или нет другой код, что
  ведет к ошибкам.

Ну и еще, прежде чем все копипасть лучше сначала разобраться как это работает что бы не появлялись такие вот ошибки.

Answer (score 2):

Error:(65, 9) error: unreachable statement означает, что имеется код, который не выполнится никогда. В данном случае это

```
mListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(R.id.listView, container);
mInputSearch = (EditText) inflater.inflate(R.id.inputSearch,container);
```

эти строки никогда не исполнятся, т.к. перед ними уже возвращается какое-то значение

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_list, container, false);
```

return немедленно прекращает выполнение функции

Comment: Поменял строки в таком порядке как вы написали, получаю 
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0c006c type #0x12 is not valid

Comment: `@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_list, container, false);

    mListView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    mInputSearch = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
    return v;
}`

Так будет правильно

Comment: Ошибка пропала, но по какой то причине, на экране телефона есть только табы но нету поля ввода  и списка( списка нету потому что не получается проинициализировать адаптер - NullPointerExeption )